# Best method for two git repos based off of a FOSS repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

This might have been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't quite find this particular Q&A anywhere.

There is a public repo that I plan to pull down from github.  Now let's say that I want to make some changes to the project (modifying one of their files, and adding multiple of my own files).  How can I do this so I can have a way to keep my files version controlled, but not mess up the main git project (so I can keep up to date with their development)?

Comment: Your question is vague to me.  If you want to only keep your _local_ files version controlled, then you can use Git locally and never push to the repository.  If you want to keep up to date, then you can `git pull` the changes from the remote.  If you are afraid of "messing up" the remote, then you can choose not to push, but this makes it impossible for you to share your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that using `git branch` to create a branch you will keep local for your changes, and using `git merge` or `git rebase` if you want to update your local branch would work in your case.

Comment: Note quite.  Say the git project (that I have no control over) gets pulled down and is in folder A.  Inside of folder A is file 1.txt, 2.txt, and folder B.  Inside folder B is 3.txt.  Now say that I create a file called test.txt inside folder A.  I also create a folder called C, and put a file called test2.txt in it.  How do I version control test.txt and test2.txt without messing up the original pulled down project (b/c I want to be able to fetch/merge updates as they come in)?

Comment: Well then you would create a branch say _local_ where to work. You can then use `git add`; `git commit`; `git log`; ... as usual on that branch. Then if you update your branch _master_ using `git pull`, you can switch back to _local_ and execute `git rebase master` to update your local modifications as well. This way you keep _master_ clean, and you have your _local_ branch up-to-date. I suggest you have a look at: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html.